# End to End Tracking in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have Azure resources connected to make a transaction that consists
of Azure Service bus, Logic Apps and more. I can see run details of Azure Logic Apps
but I couldn't see what is happening before the Logic app and After the Logic App. Is there a way to visualize the whole transaction in a single place in Azure portal?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, that is what azure monitor is for. You can create an azure log analytics work space: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace

> You require a Log Analytics workspace if you intend on collecting data from the following sources:
>
> - Azure resources in your subscription
> - On-premises computers monitored by System Center Operations Manager
> - Device collections from Configuration Manager
> - Diagnostics or log data from Azure storage

You can now even add application insights for customized tracking and logging but also querying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource

#### Edit

For a visual of your solution, you can use the azure service map: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/service-map

Comment: I agree with the Log Analytics but is it possible to visualize how every resource are connected in a graphical view rather than log view?

Comment: Of course, check service map: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/service-map

Comment: Thanks great. Will this Service Map be dynamically generated based on the Log Analytics or Should we define the workflow somewhere?

Comment: It is dynamically generated